# pivot and error ORA-56901: non-constant expression is not allowed

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM
(
 SELECT DATE_KEY,CELL_NAME, HOUR_KEY,HANDOVER_PREPARATION_RATE_EUCELL_ERIC_ 
FROM EDW.FCT_PRSE4G_CELL_KPI_H 

WHERE PROVINCE='KJ'
AND DATE_KEY BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY') -2,'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY') -1,'YYYYMMDD') 
AND HOUR_KEY BETWEEN 0AND 8
) 
PIVOT ( 
        SUM(HANDOVER_PREPARATION_RATE_EUCELL_ERIC_) FOR DATE_key IN ( TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY') -2,'YYYYMMDD') AS HAND_48, TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY') -1,'YYYYMMDD') AS HAND_24)
       
       )  PVT1
```

the error is about date_key and IN cluas .I used subquery in IN()
and error is  : ORA-00936 Missing EXPRESSION for "select"

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM
(
 SELECT DATE_KEY,CELL_NAME, HOUR_KEY,HANDOVER_PREPARATION_RATE_EUCELL_ERIC_ 
FROM EDW.FCT_PRSE4G_CELL_KPI_H 

WHERE PROVINCE='KJ'
AND DATE_KEY BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY') -2,'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY') -1,'YYYYMMDD') 
AND HOUR_KEY BETWEEN 0AND 8
) 
PIVOT ( 
        SUM(HANDOVER_PREPARATION_RATE_EUCELL_ERIC_) FOR DATE_key IN ( select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY') -2,'YYYYMMDD') AS HAND_48, TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY') -1,'YYYYMMDD') AS HAND_24 from dual)
       
       )  PVT1
```

Comment: Use `case` expression with the same aggregate function to pivot. It works for any database

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use dynamic keys like that in the `PIVOT`; however, you could find the number of days difference between today (at midnight) and your `date_key` and then pivot on that number:

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    (
  SELECT DATE_KEY,
         CELL_NAME,
         HOUR_KEY,
         HANDOVER_PREPARATION_RATE_EUCELL_ERIC_,
         TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(DATE_KEY, 'YYYYMMDD') AS days
  FROM   EDW.FCT_PRSE4G_CELL_KPI_H 
  WHERE  PROVINCE='KJ'
  AND    DATE_KEY BETWEEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE -2,'YYYYMMDD')
                      AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE -1,'YYYYMMDD') 
  AND    HOUR_KEY BETWEEN 0 AND 8
) 
PIVOT ( 
  SUM(HANDOVER_PREPARATION_RATE_EUCELL_ERIC_)
  FOR days IN (2 AS HAND_48, 1 AS HAND_24)
) PVT1
```

*Note 1: It is considered bad practice to store dates as strings; use a `DATE` data-type instead.*

*Note 2: Never use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE` (such as `SYSDATE`). At best, it will do nothing but, at worst, it will either raise an exception or generate an unexpected result.*

Comment: dear I need to see the hour_key in the first row and I used unpivot

Comment: @saeedeh Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76565122/edit) and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data **AND** your expected output for that data. The query does show `hour_key` so it is unclear what your problem is. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z8wQqAU3)